# HTML img won't resize with CSS, no matter what I try

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to update the front page of my companies website, but nothing appears to be working.

This is how the one part I need help with looks:

[Images are wrongly sized, with or without the CSS. Image included here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7l9k.png)

```css
.homepageImage1{
   
}
.homepageImage1 p{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
.homepageImage1 img{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
.homepageImage2{
    
}
.homepageImage2 p{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
.homepageImage2 img{
    position:relative;
    height:70px;
    width:70px;
}
.homepageImage3{
    
}
.homepageImage3 p{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
.homepageImage3 img {
    position:relative;
    max-height:50px;
    max-width:50px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="homepageImage1">
    <p><img src="[the source]" /><br /><strong>Art Alexander</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="homepageImage2">
    <p><img src="[the source]" /><br /><strong>Chuck Davidson</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="homepageImage3">
    <p><img src="[the source]" /><br /><strong>Roger Miranda</strong></p>
    </div>
```

It looks correct, but there is a small problem. I can remove the CSS entirely. The images remain the exact same. I input the CSS, and the images remain the exact same.

Keep in mind each image has much larger dimensions than what is being shown.

It worked fine in previous front page adjustments.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in the <head> section on the html pages?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your images are large enough? They won't stretch to be larger with your setup.

Here is an example of how I would go about it. *When creating a targeted example* for a StackOverflow question, leave out anything that isn't necessary for the particular problem - such as your paragraph css. Also, creating a jsFiddle can often help you solve the problem yourself - or reveal that the issue may be somewhere else in your code. : )

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/wuewmcaL/

### markup

```
<div class="image-w avatar">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/800" alt="">
</div>

<div class="image-w avatar small">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/800" alt="">
</div>

<div class="image-w avatar medium">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/800" alt="">
</div>
```

### styles

```
.image-w img { /* let img respond to parent size */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.avatar {
  max-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.avatar.small {
  max-width: 80px;
}

.avatar.medium {
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: The images are large enough. They're actually roughly the same size as the huge image. The first image of Art was actually much much larger before I added the two other images onto the page.

EDIT: I checked the jsfiddle. I changed all the images to 100x100. They're now all the exact same size. However... on the website there's still no change.

Comment: Well, there is something in your CSS or code that is doing whatever is happening. Have you looked at the console or the inspector to see what the computed CSS styles are? If my example works in the fiddle, then it's something else in your program. You'll need to rethink what you've done from the start.

Comment: Your example worked, but then I copy/pasted my own code into it while changing the sizes of all images to 100x100. It changed them in the fiddle, and it worked 100%. However, on the actual home page of the site nothing has bothered to change.

I can't find anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Maybe your CSS file isn't loading properly - or you have a duplicate. Can you put a `border: 3px solid red` around them and see if that works?

Comment: There's no dupe. No border shows, so it must be the CSS not loading

Comment: Yeah. So - if you can't change any CSS - you need to find out why before you get frustrated about the avatars. : )